# How can I merge results from a SQL query that returns multiple objects with the same id?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm building my first Node.js API.
In the endpoint '/posts' I have a return like this:

```
[
    {
        "POST_ID": 1,
        "POST_TITLE": "Post N.1",
        "POST_DESCRIPTION": "Description for Post N.1",
        "POST_PHOTO_URL": "Url for image 1 of post 1"
    },
    {
        "POST_ID": 1,
        "POST_TITLE": "Post N.1",
        "POST_DESCRIPTION": "Description for Post N.1",
        "POST_PHOTO_URL": "Url for image 2 of post 1"
    },
    {
        "POST_ID": 2,
        "POST_TITLE": "Post N.2",
        "POST_DESCRIPTION": "Description for Post N.2",
        "POST_PHOTO_URL": "Url for image 1 of post 2"
    },
    {
        "POST_ID": 2,
        "POST_TITLE": "Post N.2",
        "POST_DESCRIPTION": "Description for Post N.2",
        "POST_PHOTO_URL": "Url for image 2 of post 2"
    }
]
```

How can I merge the objects that have the same POST_ID, and make the POST_PHOTO_URL an array that contains all the URLS for the same post?

I want something like this:

```
responseObj = {
    postId: 0,
    postTitle: "Post N.1",
    postDescription: "Description for Post N.1",
    postImages: ['first_url', 'second_url'],
  };
```

My SQL Query is: `SELECT P.POST_ID, P.POST_TITLE, P.POST_DESCRIPTION, PI.POST_PHOTO_URL FROM POST P INNER JOIN POST_ITEMS AS PI ON P.POST_ID = PI.POST_ID`
SQL SERVER.

Comment: This could probably be done in your SQL query with GROUP BY, but you haven't posted your query or the database you are using. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: Hello! thanks for the response. My SQL Query is: 
SELECT P.POST_ID, P.POST_TITLE, P.POST_DESCRIPTION, PI.POST_PHOTO_URL FROM POST P INNER JOIN POST_ITEMS AS PI ON P.POST_ID = PI.POST_ID.
I'm using SQL SERVER. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no SQL SERVER to test this, but your desired output could probably be created with the following query.

```
SELECT P.POST_ID AS postId, P.POST_TITLE AS postTitle, P.POST_DESCRIPTION AS postDescription, oa.postImages
FROM POST P
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT PI.POST_PHOTO_URL AS postImages
    FROM POST_ITEMS PI
    WHERE PI.POST_ID = P.POST_ID
    FOR JSON PATH
) oa
```

This should return an JSON representation of the desired POST_PHOTO_URLs.
You have to parse these to get your array.

```js
result.forEach(r => {
  r.postImages = JSON.parse(r.postImages);
})
```

Comment: Hi @jkoch, the postImages is missing from the query output. I took a screenshot for you: https://prnt.sc/9qF8s7SOHU4-

Comment: I've edited the query. Could you check if this works?

Comment: I did this and it worked: https://prnt.sc/mD_uzgoXaLMl.
thanks so much for the help. ur a god!